# what are best practices for deploying new features for spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, high-availability, sre

i have a spring boot application with too many users, and there are many incoming requests to my application, what should i do for deploying a new feature to the application without losing incoming user request and actually interrupting the application’s availability to clients ? i wanna know about best practices for my issue.

Comment: You have to add redundancy and a load balancer. Does your application uses Session Scope?

Comment: There are multiple deployment strategies that could be employed. For your specific use case you may use something like blue green deployment strategies.
Again as @SimonMartinelli mentioned you could have Load Balancer effectively here.

Follow-up question :-  Does your application needs to respond to request in real time or  non-real time.

Comment: thanks you so much for keyword blue green. i'm going to study that in details.

Answer (score 0):

Please note deployment strategies depends on the nature of your application.

For cases like you mentioned **Blue/Green or Canary** would be useful.

Various ways Deployment strategies classified, below is one such categorization.

- Recreate: Version A is terminated then version B is rolled out.
- Ramped (also known as rolling-update or incremental): Version B is
  slowly rolled out and replacing version A.
- Blue/Green: Version B is released alongside version A, then the traffic is 
  switched to version B.
- Canary: Version B is released to a subset of users, then proceed to a full rollout. A/B testing: Version B is released to a subset of users under specific condition.
- Shadow: Version B receives real-world traffic alongside version A and doesn’t impact the response.

reference link - https://thenewstack.io/deployment-strategies/